# Writing a map to a csv

Tags: csv, go

I've been attempting to figure out how to properly write a map to a csv file with no luck.

I essentially have a program that queries an sql database, I store one of the return values as the key to the map, and then a slice of string for the data related to it that's returned, as an example the map would be:

```
var m = make(map[string][]string)

m['test1'] = [5, 4, 3]
```

so writing it to a csv would be

> test1, 5, 4, 3

Its printed to the csv just like a list/slice would be, I'm storing it in a map to make it easier to construct dynamic queries elsewhere.

I've attempted using a for loop such that:

```
for key, value := range m{
    writer.Write(key)
    writer.Write(value)
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> cannot use key (type string) as type []string in argument to writer.Write

I've done a lot of googling and searching here and can't seem to find a way to do this properly.

Comment: You have to construct a temporary slice of string, set index 0 to the map key and append the map value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Package csv](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/)
>
> [func (*Writer) Write](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Writer.Error)
>
> ```
> func (w *Writer) Write(record []string) error
> ```
>
> Writer writes a single CSV record to w along with any necessary
>   quoting. A record is a slice of strings with each string being one
>   field.

---

> error: cannot use key (type `string`) as type `[]string` in argument to
>   `writer.Write`

---

> "I've done a lot of googling and searching here."

To solve this problem, read the documentation of `Write` and follow the instructions in the error message, You have type `string`, `Write` wants type `[]string`. For example,

```
for key, value := range m {
    r := make([]string, 0, 1+len(value))
    r = append(r, key)
    r = append(r, value...)
    err := writer.Write(r)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
}
writer.Flush()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little new to the language some of the docs are a tad confusing, this makes perfect sense, was attempting to avoid making a temporary slice but it seems that would be the way to do it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dangle: A slice is a `struct` with a length, a capacity, and a pointer to an underlying array, 24  ( 3 *( 64 / 8)) bytes on a 64-bit architecture. `make([]string, 0, 1+len(value))` allocated the exact size for the slice's underlying array of `string`s, which avoids reallocations during `append`. A `string` is a `struct` with a length and a pointer to the underlying string bytes.

Comment: @Dangle: When the value of r is created we are allocating and copying slice descriptors (`structs`). We don't allocate or copy the string values, only the pointers to them. So it is not very expensive.

Comment: What to do if the value is int type instead of string?